# How to increase columns in pandas if a certain condition is satisfied?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe for example:

```
ID      Description 

1       Long lasting glasses,Fire resistant,Polarizer
```

I want every description column just containing the maximum length of 10 characters, if it exceeds new columns should be formed. Example:

```
ID   Description   Description2   Description3  Description4   Description5

1    Long Lasti     ng glasses    ,Fire resi     stant,Pola    rizer
```

Comment: @Ch3steR Its not a dupe.

Comment: @Ch3steR, I'm totally disagree! Do you know a regular expression that splits on length???

Comment: Reopened guys. Sorry I jumped the gun. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) + [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html)

We can `extract` the all the occurrences of capturing group in the regex pattern, then `unstack` to reshape

```
df['Description'].str.extractall(r'(.{10}|.+$)')[0].unstack()
```

---

```
match           0           1           2           3      4
0      Long lasti  ng glasses  ,Fire resi  stant,Pola  rizer
```

**Regex Details:**

- `(.{10}|.+$)` : First capturing group

  - `.{10}` : Match any character exactly 10 times (First alternative)
  - `.+` : Match any character one or more times (Second alternative)

See the [`online regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/s2kZH7/1)

Comment: Thanks @Ch3steR yeah squeeze would also work nicely.

Comment: the column names are also important, any ideas for it

Comment: @AtomStore We can `add` a prefix to the column names. Please check `df['Description'].str.extractall(r'(.{10}|.+$)')[0].unstack().add_prefix('Description')`